# Express web server is returning status 200 when it should 404

Tags: node.js, express, webserver, iptables

I know people are scanning my server to use it as an open proxy. I am running nodejs through an express framework on an amazon cloud machine. I am using iptables to port forward port 80 to 8080 so I can avoid running it as a root user.

```
GET http://www.baidu.com/ 200 1.484 ms - 6482
GET http://yahoo.com/ 200 1.557 ms - 6482
GET /css/index.css 304 1.310 ms - -
```

Obviously yahoo and baidu are not part of my domain so shouldn't they return 404?

When I use

```
curl --proxy <<mywebsite>> http://yahoo.com
```

I get the html for my root page instead of yahoo. Why is this not 404ing?

Comment: This is something that you should do with a reverse proxy, not iptables. A reverse proxy will check whether the URL being accessed is the correct one and return 404 if it isn't. Apache and nginx both provide this functionality and it's very common to use them for this purpose.

Comment: Then what is the point of using an express web server?

Comment: Apache/nginx share a bit of functionality with Express for sure. However express is a framework for writing dynamic web pages/services which contains amongst other things a web server which is very easy and convenient to use. Apache/nginx are however designed to serve static content but have this additional functionality built in. You don't need them for your use case. They're just very commonly used for it and well documented. There are dozens of reverse proxies that you can use. (Like [redbird](https://github.com/OptimalBits/redbird))

Comment: Sweet, thanks bro. Got any good resources on an example nginx/apache/redbird and express build

Comment: Redbird seems simple enough though i have never used it. Here is a link to a tutorial for setting up apache as reverse proxy. https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/12/tutorial-apache-2-4-transparent-reverse-proxy/